# C# Error In My Code Source (using System.Net.Http)

Tags: c#

Langage : C# / 
Codded Using : Visual Studio / 
Using The System.Net.Http.dll

Hello , Please help Me I have 4 error in my code source project created in C# here is all error :

(I am a beginner) but if you can post the code cleaned fixed I thank you very much

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYBnX.png)
[Error 1 (Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXKUj.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeO1Y.png)
[Error 2 (Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/map5Z.png)

[Error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVVVr.png)
[Error 3 (Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LrRj.png)

[Error 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuWuX.png)
[Error 4 (Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReBvo.png)

```css
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CheckerProject
{
    public partial class Checker
    {
        public Checker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Check()
        {
            string text = this.textBox1.Text;
            using (HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = (DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate)
            })
            {
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                {
                    TaskAwaiter<HttpResponseMessage> taskAwaiter = httpClient.PostAsync("https:\\API.com", new StringContent("{\"onlineId\":\"" + text + "\",\"reserveIfAvailable\":false}".ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).GetAwaiter();
                    if (!taskAwaiter.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        await taskAwaiter;
                        TaskAwaiter<HttpResponseMessage> taskAwaiter2;
                        taskAwaiter = taskAwaiter2;
                        taskAwaiter2 = default(TaskAwaiter<HttpResponseMessage>);
                    }
                    HttpResponseMessage result = taskAwaiter.GetResult();
                    taskAwaiter = default(TaskAwaiter<HttpResponseMessage>);
                    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = result;
                    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage2 = httpResponseMessage;
                    httpResponseMessage = null;
                    TaskAwaiter<string> taskAwaiter3 = httpResponseMessage2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter();
                    if (!taskAwaiter3.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        await taskAwaiter3;
                        TaskAwaiter<string> taskAwaiter4;
                        taskAwaiter3 = taskAwaiter4;
                        taskAwaiter4 = default(TaskAwaiter<string>);
                    }
                    string result2 = taskAwaiter3.GetResult();
                    taskAwaiter3 = default(TaskAwaiter<string>);
                    string text2 = result2;
                    string text3 = text2;
                    text2 = null;
                    if (httpResponseMessage2.StatusCode.ToString() == "429")
                    {
                        //Function
                    }
                    if (httpResponseMessage2.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                    {
                        if (httpResponseMessage2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                        {
                            //Function
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Function
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Function
                        if (text3.Contains("Online id already exists"))
                        {
                            //Function
                        }
                        if (text3.Contains("Improper"))
                        {
                            //Function
                        }
                    }
                    httpResponseMessage2 = null;
                    text3 = null;
                }
                HttpClient httpClient = null;
            }
            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Part of your problem is you're using stuff you're (mostly) warned away from: [`TaskAwaiter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) isn't meant to be used directly.  Is there some reason you're not just `await`ing the `Task`s returned by the given methods?  The other thing is the way you 'clear' variables by setting them to null - is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: Do not use `TaskAwaiter` or `GetAwaiter`, just `await` the async methods, e.g. `await httpClient.PostAsync(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer the first two errors (they are the same problem).

You should remove the following 2 lines:

```
HttpClient httpClient = null;
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = null;
```

What you do here is you declare 2 **NEW** variables and assign the value `'null'` to both of them.

What you meant to do is propably to assign `'null'` to the existing variables. However that's not needed, since they are declared inside a `'using'` block, which will automatically call the `'Dispose'` method.